# Using the default public function index() in creating custom controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter framework and just thought to ask this when I am studying the framework. I just want to ask, is including the function `public function index(){....}` before adding other functions after that? Or you can not necessary add the function and just load a view? For example, if I don't create the `public function index(){...}` and just add a function, let's say `public function test_index(){..}` and inside it is load the view..

Answer (score 0):

I see the whole point now. I can add a function other than the `public function index(){..}` and just call or load the view inside it. For example:

```
public function test_index(){
$this->load->view('home_view);
}
```

and just view in the browser together with the class and the function..

Answer (score 0):

You can add other functions as you wish with or without index